# how do I remove the charcter - from Angular SQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I use the following code for fetching data From a PHP server running MySQL.  This JSON data is then used in  angularjs ng-repeats to populate mobile applications  What I would like to know if there is a way to remove the - from phone numbers etc..   example 1-999-666-8888 would become 19996668888.  In the past I just entered the phone numbers in the database without the - character. Going forward I would like to reuse these databases to populate printed documents where the reader expects the - character in the phone numbers.  can this be done in PHP or will I have do this at the mobile application level

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","User","Password","Database");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT name, position, phone, cell, sms, email FROM contacts");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"name":"'  . $rs["name"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"position":"'   . $rs["position"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"phone":"'   . $rs["phone"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"cell":"'   . $rs["cell"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"sms":"'   . $rs["sms"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"email":"'. $rs["email"]     . '"}'; 
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?
```

Comment: You should make use of json_encode to output data to your angular application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit in the docs I came up with replacing, echo($outp); 
with, echo str_ireplace("-","",$outp);  if any one has a better or more efficient answer I would appreciate your answer as I make no claims on being an expert on php.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to do with pure JavaScript.

```
var withoutHyphens = withHyphens.replace(/-/g, "");
```

This is one of a hundred ways to do this. You can do it on the server if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  My best case would to remove it at the Server.  Once this information hits the App it gets used for searches, saving to to a local database on the device etc..  All the Apps I build are on Enterprise License(s) so I don't have to worry about Apple, Android, Blackberry, and windows phone store guidelines